# Postgresql regexp_replace 'g' flag

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, regexp-replace

i have string
    `[[good|12345]] [[bad1 [[bad2 [[bad3 [[bad4 [[bad5 [[good|12345]]`

i need to kill `[[` if word havent `|` after it.

what i do:
`select regexp_replace('[[good|12345]] [[bad1 [[bad2 [[bad3 [[bad4 [[bad5 [[good|12345]]', 
'\[\[([^\|]+?(\[\[|\Z))', '\1', 'g')`

what i get:
`[[good|12345]] bad1 [[bad2 bad3 [[bad4 bad5 [[good|12345]]`

what i want to get:
`[[good|12345]] bad1 bad2 bad3 bad4 bad5 [[good|12345]]`

it looks like the last 2 symbols of my regexp `[[` doesn't exists in next iteration of regexp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a look-ahead instead of a group:

```
select regexp_replace('[[good|12345]] [[bad1 [[bad2 [[bad3 [[bad4 [[bad5 [[good|12345]]', '\[\[([^\|]+?(?=\[\[|\Z))', '\1', 'g')
```

See [demo SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/16394/1)

[image]

The `(?=\[\[|\Z)` look-ahead only *checks* the presence of `[[`, but does not *consume* the characters (i.e. matches and moves on through the string). Thus, the following `[[` remain available for the next match.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, should i set `?=` to the each member of group? Will it be difference between `(?=a|b)` and `(?=a|?=b)`

Comment: A negative lookahead `(?=\[\[|\Z)` checks if there are `[[` or end of line. If you write `(?=a|?=b)` you will get an error since alternation operator `|` cannot be quantified (there can be no 1 or more alternation operations at 1 single location in string). If you write `(?=a)(?=b)` the expression will never match as 1 and the same character at a given position cannot be `a` and `b` at the same time (lookarounds perform the check without consuming text, they do it while still staying at the same place where the lookaround came into play.